# Does everything disappear when I block someone on Facebook and Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-messenger

If I block someone on Facebook and also block him on Messenger, does everything on Messenger disappear or still is shown as active from the person that blocked him ?

Comment: You seem to be asking about Facebook, but you've tagged this "yahoo". What are you talking about?

Comment: Indeed, if the second half of your question is about Yahoo! Messenger and not Facebook Messenger, please edit your question accordingly because I removed the "yahoo" tag. Also try to rephrase your whole question better, it can hardly make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you block someone on Facebook or Messenger, you both will not be able to see each others activities and also not be able to send messages. Old conversation will be still in inbox but name of that person will not be clickable.

See the [Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/131930530214371) to understand blocking:

> What is blocking? What happens when I block someone?

> You can [block someone](https://www.facebook.com/help/168009843260943) to unfriend them and prevent them from starting conversations with you or seeing things you post on your profile.

> People you block can no longer:

- See things you post on your profile
- Tag you
- Invite you to events or groups
- Start a conversation with you
- Add you as a friend

> Blocking is reciprocal, so you also won't be able to do things like start a conversation with them or add them as a friend. Keep in mind that blocking someone may not prevent all communications or interactions, such as in apps or groups, and only affects your experience on Facebook, not elsewhere on the web.

> **Note:** Removing a block will not restore the friend connection. If you block a friend and then remove that person from your block list, you'll need to send them a new friend request.

Comment: "you both will not be able to each others activities" … you both will not be able to *what* each others activities?

Comment: @KyleDelaney thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the answer.